# Automapper: setting AllowNullCollections on the profile

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper to map a class with a null collection to a destination with the same collection. I need the destination collection to also be null.

There is a property on the Profile class called AllowNullCollections. It is not affecting the mapping. 
If I set cfg.AllowNullCollections to True the mapping does leave the destination collection as null (as I want).

I can't set the AllowNullCollections to True for all mappings in my system, it must only apply to my profile.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;


namespace Radfords.FreshCool.Web.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("UnitTest")]
    class AutomapperTests
    {
        private IMapper _mapper;

        // this says that AllowNullCollections does work at the profile level, in May. 
        //https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1264

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<TestMappingProfile>();
                // I want the profile to set the configuration, if I set this here the test passes
                //cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            });
            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }


        [Test]
        [Category("UnitTest")]
        public void MapCollectionsTest_MustBeNull()
        {
            var actual = _mapper.Map<Destination>(new Source());

            Assert.IsNull(actual.Ints, "Ints must be null.");
        }

    }

    internal class TestMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public TestMappingProfile()
        {
            AllowNullCollections = true;

            CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
        }
    }

    internal class Source
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> Ints { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Destination
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> Ints { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bug. I have [submitted an issue about it to the repo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1618) to get some more information

Comment: But, one thing to add: "I can't set the AllowNullCollections to True for all mappings in my system, it must only apply to my profile." - this is the intention. Profiles do not change global settings, only settings for the types they map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes to clarify I can't set allownullcollections to true on the config because it'll apply globally, I want to set allownullcollections to true at the profile level, just for my specific mapping.

Comment: Yeah, this code would work as you expected then in version 4.2x. Something seems to have changed in 5x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will Ray has submitted an issue on github. The current state is that you cannot set AllowNullCollections at the profit level, you must set it at the config level.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace TestMappingProfile Ctor with below and it should work :

```
public TestMappingProfile()
{

CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.Ints, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.Ints != null)));            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The classes I am mapping have many collections so specifying the mapping at a member level isn't ideal.